# Python - Search all files for "exit 0" string

Tags: python, search, glob

I'm trying to use python to search through a directory of files and open every single file in search of a string.

We're talking about less than 1000 files with 1, 2, 3 line each, so opening them all only takes a few seconds.

Well, I think that I've made it, but there's a problem: the string that I'm search for is "**exit 0**".

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

import glob

scriptsdir = "/dummydir/*.ksh"
string = "exit 0"
files = glob.glob(scriptsdir)
teste = 0

for script in files:
    f=open(script,"r")
    for line in f:
        if string in line:
            teste = teste + 1
    f.close()    
print teste
```

This sucks because the code is working: like this, the "teste" value at the end refers to number of .ksh files on the directory, but if change the string to **exit 1**, the value of the "teste" in the end is 0. I'm literally searching for an "**exit 0**" string that exists in some of those files.

Is it possible to do it? I've tested it and if I change the string value to something that exists, the count is done right.

Any help?

Thank you,

Comment: when you print the "line" variable, what do you get? are you getting "exit 0" string included?

Comment: You're counting *number* of lines, not number of files. To count number of files, break after the match was found in a file.

Answer (score 0):

Your counter is increased for every line that matches; if a file has that string more than once, the counter will be increased for each match.

You can fix this by adding a break after the counter increment. This will cause Python to move on to the next file straight away.

Answer (score 0):

You could probably go with reading all the contents `f.read()`.

```
#!/usr/bin/env python
import glob
scriptsdir = "/dummydir/*.ksh"
string = "exit 0"
files = glob.glob(scriptsdir)
teste = 0

for script in files:
    f=open(script,"r")
    if string in f.read():
        teste = teste + 1
    f.close()    
print teste
```

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for your comments. As soon as I started printing the "line" value I noticed that he was getting the "exit 0" from somewhere else, looked up to the script again and found that a third script was being called inside of the file that has the exit 0 written.

I dont agree with this way of doing stuff but I dont have enough power to change the way things are done, so after that I could solve my problem and saw searching for "exit 0" was not my problem at all.

Cheers